# Which hoster for asp.net application using BlackfishSQL?

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, mono

I am working on a asp.net application based on a desktop app I wrote which will use BlackfishSQL as its backend. Now I need a hoster.

I think I can deploy this on Linux using Mono (and I will in fact test it that way) which means I have options and can choose between Windows and Linux hosts. BlackfishSQL itself is managed code.

Can someone point me to a good Web hosting company offering Linux or Windows servers for projects like mine? I don't think I need much traffic and certainly not much disk space. I do, however, need .NET 2.0 (possibly higher) and Mono 2.4 or higher.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a budget or a range of budget for the hosting piece of this.

Comment: I didn't include a budget range because there isn't one. The application is small and won't have many users so obviously I wouldn't want to spend a lot of money. But I haven't yet thought about how much I would want to pay because I have no idea how much this can cost.

Comment: Delphi Prism now comes without BlackfishSQL and I am now using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get something like this you are going to need to with a Dedicated or Virtual solution at minimum to be able to get the setup you need.  I personally would recommend just going with Windows Server if you can since you are doing .NET, but that is just me.

I'm a Rackspace partner and find their offerings to be pretty good.  From a virtual hosting perspective I have used Hosting.com with great success.

I'm also a partner with The Planet, and they by far have some of the best prices, but have only used them a limited amount.

Comment: Ta. I'll have a look. I saw a Linux VM hoster advertising on ServerFault but I cannot find it any more. Anyone remember which one it was?

Comment: I have a current client that has been using APlus.net successfully for a while.  They have a pretty neat hybrid that can run your site on both Linux and Windows.  They also seem pretty reasonably priced.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [DiscountASP.Net](http://www.discountasp.net/) for several clients over the years and can say that they are quite good. BUT... I've never tried deploying BlackfishSQL (is that a Delphi thing?  I used to love Delphi.) and your mileage may vary.

Comment: BlackfishSQL is a managed database that comes with Delphi Prism. I assume native Delphi also uses it. I'll have a look at DiscountASP.NET. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can now say that I have used the Economy Virtual Dedicated Hosting at GoDaddy (cranked one up this weekend when I needed full trust for a site) and found it pretty quick and nice.  They got the VM provisioned quickly and it has a pretty interesting balance of space and power.  I am running a .NET CMS system on top of SQL Express and WordPress on MySQL side by side without a problem.  A Virtual Dedicated is much cheaper than a full box that can handle the same traffic spikes.

Comment: I got 8 cores, 512 MB RAM, and a 10GB drive for $30/month.

Comment: I'll have a look. Ta.